# sbt throws error while launching it

Tags: java, scala, build, sbt

i am trying command `sbt package` after sbt installation, it throws following error.

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.12 ...
java.lang.InternalError
        at sun.security.ec.SunEC.initialize(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ec.SunEC.access$000(SunEC.java:49)
        at sun.security.ec.SunEC$1.run(SunEC.java:61)
        at sun.security.ec.SunEC$1.run(SunEC.java:58)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.ec.SunEC.<clinit>(SunEC.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:221)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:206)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:206)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:145)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:102)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.lang.InternalError
```

i am using RHEL 6.5 and my Java version is `java version "1.7.0_111"`. Help me to resolve this error.

Comment: There's a problem with your JVM installation; it looks like an SSL cipher library isn't linking properly.

Comment: thanks chrylis, i reinstalled jvm and now i am getting unresolved dependency error.

Comment: Where are you installing Java from? Can you show the new error message?

Comment: Server access Error: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.KeyException url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.12/sbt-0.13.12.pom
Server access Error: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.KeyException url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.12/sbt-0.13.12.jar
Server access Error: java.security.ProviderException: java.security.KeyException url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.12/ivys/ivy.xml
this was the error i am getting, installed JDK 1.8

Answer (score 1):

I am using openSuse Leap and I had the same issue with sbt and "java.lang.InternalError" today using both last openJDK8 and oracleJDK8 as well.

What helped me is making a system update. It looks like newer NSS library is required, please check https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1332456 for more details.